# Illumina Overview Tutorial validate_mapping_file.py not found

Tags: python, bioinformatics, qiime

I am new to `QIIME`. By following the Illumina overview tutorial, I ran:

```
!validate_mapping_file.py -o vmf-map/ -m map.tsv
```

and then I got an error message:

```
/bin/sh: validate_mapping_file.py: command not found
```

I also try to run command

`!qiime`, `!MacQIIME` and `!QIIME`, but my computer also cannot find those commands.

I have installed the `QIIME`, the command:

```
source activated qiime
```

Works well

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the file validate_mapping_file.py in your working directory or in your path? If yes try to make it executable: ```chmod +x validate_mapping_file.py``` or call it via python: ```python validate_mapping_file.py -o vmf-map/ -m map.tsv```. If you cannot find the script something went wrong with your installation.

Comment: Where do you enter these commands? Did you mean `python validate_mapping_file.py -o vmf-map/ ...`?